# How to fix Syntax Error while using .cells function in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I carry on getting either "syntax error" or "expected list separator or )" on the first .cells line but it works perfectly if I remove it

I have tried changing variable names and types

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    Dim lRows As Long
    Dim col As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Activity")
    Set col = Range("A:A")

    lRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(col) + 1

    'copy the data to the database
    With ws
      .Cells(1Rows, 1).Value = 1Rows
      .Cells(lRows, 2).Value = Me.DateS.Value 
    End With
End Sub
```

it should out put a number one after the last one in column A but it gives me error instead

Comment: There is a typo `1Rows` should be `lRows` (lower case `L` not a one `1`) • I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*. That would prevent such typos. • I recommend to specify the sheet for `Range("A:A")` like `ws.Range("A:A")`

Comment: Thank you I didn't even notice it until i put the code in here because in excel they looked identical, i have turned on that setting as well.